# Next.js app with Cloudinary deployed to Render returns 400 for image

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cloudinary, render.com

Next.js and Cloudinary works great in local env but in deployment in the cloud I get ""url" parameter is not allowed"
in localhost the request is:

http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=<valid_and_works_cloudinary_url>
return 200

in development the request is:

[https://digital-resume-frontend-dev.onrender.com/_next/image?url=\](https://digital-resume-frontend-dev.onrender.com/_next/image?url=%5C)<valid_and_works_cloudinary_url>
return 400 "url" parameter is not allowed

I tried to add CORS env var to Render

I tried to add my domain to Cloudinary Allowed fetch domains

Comment: There is a need to configure the next.config.js file to allow your app to load external images. Additionally, you will need to add make the `/app/next.config.js` file available in the app root directory `./` - [see this documentation](https://www.gyanblog.com/javascript/nextjs-fixing-load-external-images-url-parameter-not-allowed/)

Comment: thx for your response, I've added the domains to the next.config.js and it's located in the root directory